# Storyboard interface not working on device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uistoryboard

i have a calendar view for iphone that i copied to an ipad view, by doing that i got a problem with the storyboard interface, the changes im making on the Storyboard are not getting passed to the device, here is the problem, the example im showing is a calendar im building:

[image: The design in the storyboard interface]

[image: The view on the iPad]

Has you can see, something is very wrong, i edited the autosizing but still no change, what kind of sorcery is this?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the calendar view is the `view` property of the associated view controller. In this case it will try to claim the entire screen by default.

You need to add the calendar view as a **subview** of the main view of your view controller. The best strategy to keep the controller compatible with both iPad and iPhone is to change the iPhone one to this scheme as well. (i.e. main `view` and a subview `calendarView` which should have the same size and bounds as `view`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is in all the views, i copied the entire interface of the iphone to the ipad view and edited the ipad view, the problem is that the changes on all the views dont appear on the device.

Comment: Can you explain a litle bit better, im a bit lost with the solution that you gave, sorry for bothering.

Comment: Hmm, in this case you should perhaps get ahold of a text book or good tutorial on basic iPhone programming. Also, you can read Apple's [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).